# What happens if we copy neo4j's data folder while the server is running?

Tags: backup, neo4j

If my neo4j server is running and I copy the data folder using copy/rsync folder, what are the chances of data corruption?

Answer (score 1):

The copied store might be corrupted, but also might be recoverable.

There's a good reason neo4j has a backup tool: this method is not safe.

If you need to snapshot the file system, cleanly shut down the DB first.

Comment: Thanks for contributing, Jim.  It's also helpful to have links or references for questions like this (maybe an overview of the backup tool since the asker is using a hazardous method currently?)

Comment: If i make a copy of the data folder can it make the original folder corrupt?